# На "своей" или на "нашей"?

Tags: местоимения

Добрый день!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать в приглашении на свадьбу следующие предложения:
1) Приглашение от лица невесты: "Буду рада видеть тебя свидетельницей на (своей) (моей) (нашей) свадьбе". 
2) Приглашение от лица жениха и невесты: "Будем рады видеть тебя на (своей) (нашей) свадьбе"

Comment: @Alex_ander, спасибо за ответ!
@Виталина_ZX, спасибо за подсказку!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Своей" почему-то не очень подходит, возможно, потому, что свадьба ещё впереди и не стала "собственностью" (у меня будет свадьба, и на эту мою свадьбу я приглашу...), или как-то момент предвкушения действует на выбор местоимений. О прошедшей свадьбе - нормально воспринимается: я пригласила её на свою свадьбу.

Буду рада... на моей/нашей (в зависимости от степени знакомства гостя с женихом)

Будем рады... на нашей (обе подписи обязательно)